# Steam PlayOnLlinux-based custom shortcut

Tags: steam, linux

I'm trying to create a custom Steam Library shortcut for a PlayOnLinux game.

The problem is that, even without the `--run` option, PlayOnLinux fails to start. It looks like the Steam does something to the environment that confuses PlayOnLinux in terms of its Python runtime dependency. Here's the relevant output for a launch:

```
Game update: AppID 0 "Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri", ProcID 19059, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Looking for python... ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 19065 != 19062, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 19067 != 19062, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
2.7.6 - unexpected version
Looking for python2.7... ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 19070 != 19062, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 19072 != 19062, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
2.7.6 - unexpected version
Looking for python2.6... ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 19076 != 19062, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)

Looking for python2... ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 19078 != 19062, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
pid 19080 != 19062, skipping destruction (fork without exec?)
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/myuser/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
2.7.6 - unexpected version
Please install python before trying to run this program
Game removed: AppID 0 "Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri", ProcID 19059
```

Compare with normal PlayOnLinux output when launching it directly:

```
[main] Message: PlayOnLinux (4.2.5) is starting
[clean_tmp] Message: Cleaning temp directory
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 32bits direct rendering is enabled
[Check_OpenGL] Message: 64bits direct rendering is enabled
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/lod/.PlayOnLinux/
[main] Message: Filesystem is compatible
```

The question is, simply, **how to make a shortcut in Steam that will launch PlayOnLinux successfully**?

Comment: For Alpha Centauri in specific, can't you just `dosbox` it?

Comment: @Shadur: no idea, especially since SMAC, at least in the newer patches, is Windows based. However, Alpha Centauri is just an example, the question concerns running through PlayOnLinux in general.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shortcut file that runs the steam gameId like this:

```
steam://run/id
Example: steam://run/4000
```

or You could type that in cmd using python like this:

```
import os
os.system("start steam://run/game_id")
```

Comment: Not sure what you what you mean by the `start` command. Is this something specific to certain Linux distributions maybe?

Comment: @mikołak I mean typing it in a command prompt sorry I wasnt soo specific you could do
import os
os.system("start steam://run/id")